# Double for loop with arrylist that are changing size

Tags: java, debugging, for-loop, arraylist

The situation is that I have two nested for loops that are each iterating through an arraylist of objects. The outer for loop grabs the object at the current index and adds it two another arraylist called tempCurrEmp. The inner for loop is then suppose to go through and remove all objects in the original arraylist that are the same at a specific field. The problem is that it is not removing all copies and I do not know why. I am assuming it has something to do with the indexes changing after I call remove but I can be sure. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
for(int i=0;i<tempAllEmp.size();i++){
                tempCurrEmp.add(tempAllEmp.get(i));
                tempEmp = tempAllEmp.get(i);
                Log.d("LOOP", "Curr emp is: " + tempAllEmp.get(i).getEmployee());
                for(int j=i+1;j<tempAllEmp.size();j++){
                    Log.d("LOOP", "Comparing:" + tempEmp.getEmployee() + " and " + tempAllEmp.get(j).getEmployee().trim());
                    if(tempAllEmp.get(j).getEmployee().trim().equals(tempEmp.getEmployee())){
                        Log.d("LOOP", "They were equal");
                        tempCurrEmp.add(tempAllEmp.get(j));
                        tempAllEmp.remove(j);

                    }
                }
                maxPunch.add(getMaxPunch(tempCurrEmp));
                tempCurrEmp.clear();                    
            }
```

Comment: You didn't trim the tempEmp.getEmployee() as well

Comment: So, you want to have unique elements on the result list, haven't you? I mean, each objects on the list should have unique `employee` property.

Comment: If you posted a minimally working example, that I can just copy, paste, compile, and run, I'd be glad to give it a try. I think you need to decrement `i` (`i--`) after every removal.

Comment: You are not supposed to remove items from a collection while itterating over the collection.  You will have nothing but headaches with concurrency.  Best is to create a "remove" collection, add the ones that need to be removed, then do a `removeAll()` at the end.  Also, you are probably missing stuff because your comparisons are messed up.  SOP (`System.out.println`) each comparison to see if there is a match.

Comment: I don't think he's changing anything in the list with index < i. The second for loop always checks at i + 1, so no need to decrement i?

Comment: im pretty sure diddles is right

Comment: `j` is set to `i + 1`, which is based on the *original* length. Which is wrong as soon as the first removal occurs. BOTH `i` and `j` need to be decremented. `j` so it`s accurate immediately after the removal, and `i` so it`s accurate on the next iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: i tried i-- but that leaves me with an index out of bounds exception. i=-1

Comment: i is not based on the original length, i is based on the current position, and the OP is not removing elemnts before i

Comment: Wait a minute. I going on the assumption that `size()` is always going to be the original length (meaning evaluated only once, at the initial call to the for-loop). If it's updated properly (it's initial value is not hard coded for the rest of the loop), then yes, only `j` need be decremented. Sorry.

Comment: I'm pretty sure just j needs to be decremented after removal, like Teg answered

Comment: That what I thought too, and it seemed to work at first but something is still not quite right with that

Comment: BTW if a employee is removed you add it 2 times to the tempCurrEmp, getMaxPunch will find it twice

Comment: wait why ? because that is the problem

Comment: You add any element in the outer loop at the tempCurrEmp, then before to remove an element in the inner loop you add it to the tempCurrEmp but you are sure that it is the duplicate of the element added before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ArrayList public E remove(int index) 
>   Removes the element at the specified
>   position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left
>   (subtracts one from their indices).

So you must substract 1 to your j after removing

```
tempAllEmp.remove(j--);
```

And fix the compare:

```
if(tempAllEmp.get(j).getEmployee().equals(tempEmp.getEmployee())){
```

Comment: That's not true. `j` is based on `i`. So decrementing it is only going to work until the end of the current iteration. Then it's going to wrong again. You need to decrement `i`.

Comment: Actually, `j` *and* `i` need to be decremeted.

Comment: After the current iteration i is correct, the size of the array is shortened by the remove. If you decrement i you'll redo the current sub iteration

Comment: I've been edumicatiated. See my comments under the original post. Only `j` needs to be decremented.

Comment: actually this seems to be the correct answer but I think there is a bug elsewhere. Once im sure the loops are correct ill accept. Thanks!

Comment: I actually was making the same mistake in one other location. So thank  you for that as well. If I could accept twice I would

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to trim the  `tempEmp.getEmployee()`  as well when comparing to  `tempAllEmp.get(j).getEmployee().trim()`  ?

Comment: The trim is not important i was just using it to debug thanks though

Comment: Okay. Your if statement also uses a trimmed tempAllEmp.getEmployee() but I guess it doesn't matter there either?

Answer (score 0):

All in all, you have just took one list and put it to another one, becuase:

//You find 2 same employes

```
tempCurrEmp.add(tempAllEmp.get(i));
tempEmp = tempAllEmp.get(i);
```

// then you try to figure out if the Employ that you just find from temAllEmp REALLY REALLY exists in the tempAllEmp

```
for(int j=i+1;j<tempAllEmp.size();j++){
if(tempAllEmp.get(j).getEmployee().trim().equals(tempEmp.getEmployee())){                        tempCurrEmp.add(tempAllEmp.get(j));
tempAllEmp.remove(j);
}
```

// and if you find one, then you first add him to the current employes list and then you remove him from last All employes list, I am supprised that this did not end in an exception

```
tempCurrEmp.add(tempAllEmp.get(j));
tempAllEmp.remove(j);
```

====================================================

Try this:

```
List<Employee> currentEmployees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
for(int i=0 ; i <= tempAllEmp.size() ; i++ ){
    if(! currentEmployess.contains(templAllEmp.get(i))){
        currentEmployees.add(templAllEmp.get(i));
    }
}
```

plus have your equals() method in Employee class something like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof Employee)) {
        return false;
    }
    Employee other = (Employee) obj;
    return this.employeeId.equals(other.employeeId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely change your algorithm and use `Set`. See below example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        // generate data
        Random random = new Random();
        while (nodes.size() < 100) {
            Node node = new Node();
            node.employee = String.valueOf(random.nextInt(10) + 1);

            nodes.add(node);
        }
        System.out.println(nodes);

        // remove duplicates
        List<Node> newNodes = getUiniqueCollection(nodes);
        System.out.println(newNodes);
    }

    private static List<Node> getUiniqueCollection(List<Node> nodes) {
        List<Node> resultNodes = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<String> employees = new HashSet<>();
        for (Node node : nodes) {
            String employee = node.employee.trim();
            if (!employees.contains(employee)) {
                employees.add(employee);
                resultNodes.add(node);
            }
        }

        return resultNodes;
    }
}

class Node {

    String employee;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return employee;
    }
}
```